# Can Minio repair the damaged node?

Tags: minio

I build a 4 nodes minio cluster,after running for some time,one node was accidentlly being deleted.When I bring the node back online,there is no data being uploaded to this node since then,only another 3 nodes is working.
Is there some way to repair the damaged node and make it work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the current setup forces you to first heal the node and then the bucket. Meaning that if you have something like:

```
minio.exe --config-dir c:\data_config server --address ":8001" d:\node1 e:\node2 f:\node3 g:\node4
```

And disk `f:` goes bad you replace such drive and then, assuming you've setup `local` as an alias you have to do:

```
// this will bring your disk up to speed
mc admin heal local
```

And then:

```
// this will bring your data up to speed
mc admin heal local/bucket - where bucket is the bucket name you want to sync
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can using `mc admin heal` command, Currently available as beta feature - its a work in progress and should fully ready in future releases.